# How can I get the client IP from a request object with Restify?

Tags: node.js, restify

I'm having a difficult time finding how to access the IP address of the REST client from a route.

```
server.get('api/foo', function(req, res, next) {
    // How can I access the IP address of the requester from here?
}
```

Comment: Try inspecting the `req` object.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This worked:

`req.connection.remoteAddress`

Answer (score 19):

The other answers won't work behind a proxy, you'll get the proxy server address in those cases.

```
req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
```

Will work behind a proxy if the proxy sets the original IP in `x-forwarded-for` header which many do by default and you can add to something like nginx very easily.

Comment: x-forwarded-for can contain a chain of forwarding hosts. You should split it on coma separator and get the first (leftmost) IP. Or the first (leftmost) public IP if you need it for geolocation for example.